# Composite a numpy array/matrix based on column values and variables?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm playing with `NumPy` and `Scipy` and I'm having trouble finding a feature in the documentation. I was thus wondering if anyone could help.

Suppose I have an array in `NumPy` with two columns and `k` rows. One column serves as an numerical indicator (e.g. `2 = male`, `1 = female`, `0 = unknown`) while the second column is perhaps a `list` of values or scores.

Lets say that I want to find the standard deviation (could be mean or whatever, I just want to apply a function) of the values for all rows with indicator 0, and then for 1, and finally, 2.

**Is there a predefined function to composite this for me?**

In `R`, the equivalent can be found in the `plyr` package. Does `NumPy` and/or `Scipy` have an equivalent, or am I stuck creating a mask for this array and then somehow filtering through this mask and then applying my function?

As always, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your description, you have a dataset something like this:

```
In [79]: x=np.random.randint(0,3,size=100)

In [80]: y=np.random.randint(0,100,size=100)

In [81]: d=np.vstack([x,y]).T

In [88]: print d[:5,:]
[[ 0 43]
 [ 1 60]
 [ 2 60]
 [ 1  4]
 [ 0 30]]
```

In this situation `numpy.unique` can be used to generate an array of unique "key" values:

```
In [82]: idx=np.unique(d[:,0])

In [83]: print idx
[0 1 2]
```

and those values used to drive a generator expression like this:

```
[113]: g=(d[np.where(d[:,0]==val),1].std() for val in idx)
```

The generator `g` will emit the standard deviation of all the entries in `d` which match each entry in the index. `numpy.fromiterator` can then be used to collect the results:

```
In [114]: print np.vstack([idx,np.fromiter(g,dtype=np.float)]).T
[[  0.          26.87376385]
 [  1.          29.41046084]
 [  2.          24.2477246 ]]
```

Note there is conversion of the keys to floating point in the last step during stacking, you might not want that depending on your data, but I did just it for illustrative purposes to have a "nice" looking final result to post.

Answer (score 2):

You can use masked array operations for that.
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html#maskedarray

To create the mask, you can use the numpy.where function, like so:

```
male_mask = numpy.where(a[:,0]==2, False, True)
female_mask = numpy.where(a[:,0]==1, False, True)
```

Then, remember to use the special functions from numpy.ma:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.ma.html

```
male_average = numpy.ma.average(ma.array(a[:,1], mask=male_mask))
```

EDIT: actually, this works just as well:

```
numpy.ma.average(ma.array(a[:,1], mask=a[:,0]!=value))
```